# Error in strsplit(M[, Field], sep) : non-character argument when using the Bibliometrix functions NetMatrix and cocMatrix?

Tags: r, function, strsplit

I'm working with the bibliometrix package, functions `cocMatrix` and `biblioNetwork`.

I read my data, `M` from an Excel spreadsheet:

```
M <- readxl::read_xlsx("prueba.xlsx")
```

Here is a sample:

```
structure(list(AU = c("CALIXTO-FLORES R", "TINOCO-IZQUIERDO W; GUAMÁN-GÓMEZ V; BUSTOS-OCHOA F; VÉLEZ-TORRES E", "RAMÍREZ-SÁNCHEZ N; DÍAZ-MURILLO MP; REYES-HARKER P; CUECA-GONZÁLEZ O", "MORENO-FERNÁNDEZ O; GARCÍA-PÉREZ F", "POLLÉ-TERTULIÉN M; CHÁVEZ-HERNÁNDEZ S; SORIS-LÓPEZ T")
```

```
str(M$AU)
#chr [1:5] "CALIXTO-FLORES R" ...
```

Here is my code:

```
A <- cocMatrix(M, "AU", sep = ";")
NetMatrix <- biblioNetwork(M, analysis = "collaboration", network = "countries", sep = ";")
```

In both cases I have the next problem:

> Error in strsplit(M[, Field], sep) : non-character argument

I tried to solve the error with the following code:

```
M$AU <- as.character(M$AU)
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix the error?

Comment: What does M actually look like? Can you show a small sample using `dput` or `str`?

Comment: Sure! If I dput variable AU: structure(list(AU = c("CALIXTO-FLORES R", "TINOCO-IZQUIERDO W; GUAMÁN-GÓMEZ V; BUSTOS-OCHOA F; VÉLEZ-TORRES E", 
"RAMÍREZ-SÁNCHEZ N; DÍAZ-MURILLO MP; REYES-HARKER P; CUECA-GONZÁLEZ O", 
"MORENO-FERNÁNDEZ O; GARCÍA-PÉREZ F", "POLLÉ-TERTULIÉN M; CHÁVEZ-HERNÁNDEZ S; SORIS-LÓPEZ T"
)

Comment: It shouldn't be a list. It has to be a character vector. You'll have to show the R command to create `M`. Edit your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
NetMatrix <- biblioNetwork(data.frame(M), analysis = "collaboration",
                           network = "countries", sep = ";")
```

It worked for me.